# Check indexes in 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm trying to write code that will play a dice game called [Pig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_(dice_game)) through the command line with a person against the computer

For the computer's player, I am using a 3D numpy array to store a game strategy based on the information current score *AI_1_current*, banked score *AI_1_bank* and opponent's banked score *human_bank*.

The idea is, each turn, the computer will check the strategy array, if the value at the index [AI_1_current, AI_1_bank, human_bank] is equal to 0, it will keep rolling, if it's equal to 1, it will bank it's current score.

Now, the problem I'm having, is the function that takes the computer's turn is not reading the array properly, and not banking when it should.

I have this code to set up the array:

```
AI_1_strategy = numpy.zeroes((100,100,100))

for i in range(10, 100):
    for j in range(10, 100):
        for k in range(10, 100):
            AI_1_strategy[i, j, k] = 1
```

Which ideally should mean, if i, j or k are greater than or equal to 10, the computer will bank every turn

Then later I have this code to check the array:

```
if AI_1_strategy[AI_1_bank, AI_1_current, human_bank] == 1: 
    AI_1_bank += AI_1_current # add current points to the bank
    AI_1_current = 0
    time.sleep(3) # 3 second delay

   if AI_1_bank >= 100: # win condition
        print "AI_1 WINS!"
    else:   
        AI_current = 0 # sets current points to 0
        print "AI has banked"
        pig_human() # moves to the player's turn

else:
    time.sleep(3) # 3 second delay
    print "AI_1 chose to keep rolling"
    pig_AI_1() # AI takes another roll
```

Despite this code, the computer will fail to bank consistently.

The problem also occurs if I instead do:

```
AI_1_strategy = numpy.ones((100,100,100))

for i in range(10, 100):
    for j in range(10, 100):
        for k in range(10, 100):
            AI_1_strategy[i, j, k] = 0
```

Except in that case, it will bank every turn regardless of the scores, when it should really stop banking once i, j or k reaches 10.

If anybody could help me out I'd greatly appreciated, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're making a small logic error.

> I have this code to set up the array:
>
> ```
> AI_1_strategy = numpy.zeroes((100,100,100))
>
> for i in range(10, 100):
>     for j in range(10, 100):
>         for k in range(10, 100):
>             AI_1_strategy[i, j, k] = 1
> ```
>
> Which ideally should mean, if i, j or k are greater than or equal to 10, the computer will bank every turn

This is incorrect: Each of i, j AND k must be >=10 to read a 1 from this array.

Comment: Wow, apparently I'm an idiot, thanks for pointing that out, much appreciated.

Comment: I've also realised why this meant it would continually roll, it needed to reach 10 points in the bank before it can bank any points, this is obviously an impossible condition to satisfy, so it would keep rolling forever.

Comment: @Paradigm84: Happens. Just change the strategy array a bit?

Comment: Yeah, it's easy enough to work around now that I know where the problem lies, I just need to set it to initially trigger the bank based on AI_current rather than AI_bank.